# How to screen share Safari or a Chrome tab on Apple TV 3?

Tags: macos, google-chrome, safari, screen-sharing, airplay

I am looking for a solution where I can share a **Safari or a Chrome tab** on Apple TV.

**Points : -**

1. I am aware of the fullscreen share using the Airplay icon.
2. It's not YouTube video I am worried about since the site has built-in AirPlay.
3. Can I do this on Firefox ?

**Is there a Chrome extension or Safari Plugin to achieve this ? Is there any other software that allows us to do this ?**

Please advice.